# Was bedeutet Etat im österreichischen?

Tags: meaning, austrian

Hier gefunden http://derstandard.at/Etat

[image]

(Falls link stirbt, österreichische Online-Zeitung mit Rubrik 'Etat'.
Unterrubriken: Medien, ORF, TV, TV-Programm, Radio, Internet, Medien-Blogs, Werbung)

Ich tippe vom Kontext auf "Presse-/Medienlandschaft", aber vielleicht weiß es auch jemand.

Comment: Für alle, die noch nicht wissen, wie wir mit doppelten Fragen und Antworten umgehen: diese Frage wurde sebstverständich nicht gelöscht, und auch alle Antworten zu dieser Frage sind im Duplikat nachzulesen, sofern sie der betreffende OP nicht selbst gelöscht hat (was bei gleichen doppelten Antworten besser wäre). Hier der Link: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/was-ist-mit-%c3%96sterreichisch-gemeint-in-sprachlicher-hinsicht

Comment: Inwiefern ist die Frage *Was ist mit »Österreichisch« gemeint (in sprachlicher Hinsicht)?* ein Duplikat von *Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einer Sprachvarietät und einem Dialekt?* Das sind zwei verschiedene Fragen, auf die ich auch zwei verschiedene Antworten gegeben habe. Leider hast du in deiner kaum nachvollziehbaren Weisheit die Antwort auf eine der beiden Fragen zur anderen Frage verschoben (wo sie nicht hingehört, weil sie die dort gestellte Frage nicht beantwortet), den Titel der Frage verändert, und eine Frage zum einem Duplikat der anderen erklärt, was keineswegs zutrifft.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: auch dies ist ein typischer Fall einer [meta]-Diskussion, die dort und nicht unter dieser Frage hier geführt werden muss. Für die Frage hier ist es nämlich völlig irrelevant, welche Frage warum wohin verschoben wurde (zur Info: deine nun geschlossene Frage stand unter heftigem Community-Disput mit Close-Reopen-War. Nachdem du keinerlei Anstrengungen unternommen hattest, deine Frage anzupassen und deine Edits die Frage noch verschlimmerten, blieb außer Löschen nur Merge-Close. Nur so konnte sowohl deine Frage als auch deine schöne Antwort erhalten bleiben.)

Answer (score 2):

**Der Etat** ist im Wirtschaftswesen ein Synonym für **das Budget**, also für den Betrag, der für irgend etwas zur Verfügung steht.

Im Militärischen Kontext ist der Etat eine veraltete Bezeichnung für die Anzahl der Personen in einer Truppe (also die Truppenstärke).

Beide Begriffe sind jedoch keine Austriazismen, sondern werden genau so im gesamten deutschsprachigen Gebiet verwendet.

Die österreichische Tageszeitung *derStandard* verwendet dieses Wort als Bezeichnung für eine ihrer Rubriken. Die Rubrik *Etat* wird weiter unterteilt in diese Sub-Rubriken:

- **Medien** (Damit sind andere österreichische Printmedien gemeint)
- **ORF** (Österreichs dominierender Fernseh- und Radio-Konzern, öffentlich-rechtlich)
- **TV** (Berichte über deutschsprachiges Fernsehen)
- **TV-Programm** (Empfehlungen der Redaktion für den aktuellen Tag)
- **Radio** (Berichte und Empfehlungen für Radio-Konsumenten)
- **Internet** (Medien-Trends die via internet bezogen werden können, z.B Netflix)
- **Medien-Blogs** (Von der Redaktion empfohlene Medien-Blogs)
- **Werbung** (Berichte über die Werbe-Branche)

Insgesamt kann man also zu dem Schluss kommen, dass die Herausgeber von *derStandard* der Meinung sind, »*Etat*« wäre ein gutes Wort um als Überschrift für alles zu dienen, was in der Welt der Medien insgesamt zur Verfügung steht.

Ob die Wahl dieses Wortes gelungen ist, kann sicherlich Anlass von Diskussionen sein. Jedenfalls ist es in der hier geschilderten Bedeutung kein eigentlicher Austriazismus, sondern eine Bedeutungs-Belegung aus dem Hause *derStandard*.

Answer (score 0):

Ja, aber das ist einfach nur der gewählte Name, kein Austriacum an sich. (So wie eine Zeitung zB Profil, Spiegel oder Stern heißen kann. Sehr ähnlich gleich daneben *Panorama*.) *Etat* hat auch im österreichischen Deutsch zunächst keine andere Bedeutung als Synonym zu Budget, vor allem in der Medien- und Werbebranche.

Answer (score 0):

Ein **Etat** ist auch ein durch einen Probedruck festgehaltener Zustand der Platte während der Entstehung eines Kupferstiches.

Vielleicht daraus die Derivation ins Medien-Lager...?