# Woher kommt der Name für das Zeitungsressort „Etat“?

Tags: meaning, austrian

Die österreichische Tageszeitung [*Der Standard*](http://derstandard.at/) – und, soweit ich erkennen kann, nur sie – enthält ein Ressort namens „[Etat](http://derstandard.at/Etat)“. Es behandelt Themen, die in anderen Zeitungen manchmal in einem Ressort „Medien“ Platz finden, häufig aber auch einen Teilbereich in einem größeren Ressort „Kultur“ oder „Feuilleton“ ausmachen.

Das französische Wort *état* bedeutet eigentlich ‘Zustand’, ‘Lage’ oder auch (dank Ludwig XIV. am bekanntesten) ‘Staat’. In Deutschland und der Schweiz bedeutet *Etat* vor allem ‘Haushaltsplan’ und ‘für ein Vorhaben zur Verfügung stehender Geldbetrag’ (laut dem Variantenwörterbuch sind diese Bedeutungen in Österreich nicht verbreitet), darüber hinaus kann es in der Schweiz ‘Mitgliederverzeichnis’ heißen, und im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum wird es fachsprachlich für den Probeabzug von einem Kupferstich verwendet.

Nichts davon scheint zum *Standard*-Ressort zu passen. Warum heißt es so? Gibt es noch eine österreichische Sonderbedeutung von *Etat*?

Comment: Hatten wir das nicht vor kurzem? http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24281/was-bedeutet-etat-im-österreichischen Oder sehe ich den Unterschied nicht?

Comment: @Stephie: Ups. Anfang Juli hatte ich wenig Zeit, da habe ich das nicht gesehen; und leider hat auch die Suche es nicht gefunden, jedenfalls nicht mit meinen Begriffen. Danke für den Hinweis, dann weg mit der Frage …

Comment: @Stephie: Als ich das letzte Mal in Österreich war, fing die Jahreszahl noch mit einer anderen Ziffer an. ;-) Nein, reiner Online-Leser. Also wohl einfach ein Zufall.